# Jquery validation engine error popup comes behind div tag

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using validation engine from http://www.position-absolute.com/ site.
The validation is applied on the div tag which is opened as popup on parent page.
Issue : when error message is shown on a control, it is appearing behind the div.

Search to similar issue suggest the usages of z-index, but how to control the z-index of error message poping from validation engine? Giving high number to div z-index:99999 did not work.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just change your script  as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $(".primary").click(function () {
        $(".formError").remove();

    });
    $(".close").click(function () {

        $(".formError").remove();
    });

    $("#yourformid").submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var validForm = $("#yourformid").validationEngine('validate');
        $(".formError").css("z-index", 15000);
        if (validForm) {
            $("#yourformid").submit();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

it works fine